# Add html widget programmatically to the list “Add fields” in views in Drupal 7

Tags: views, hooks

I'm trying to create a html widget that will be available in all views. I would like to have the widget available in the list "Add fields" in views.

The module Easy social have this functionality, but I can't figure out how they did that.

So how can I from my module programmatically add fields to the list "Add fields" for views?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This documentation will help you, just add a field handler then you are done! [Click here](http://www.heididev.com/custom-field-handlers-views-3)